# Custom View termination of my own work thread

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I have my own class called **TimerControl** that extends **android.view.View**. Inside **TimerControl**, I spawn a worker thread that should continue to work so while the Activity that the View is a part of is still alive. (i.e. onStop has not been called on the Parent Activity) I do not want to write the logic to kill the thread inside the Activity class because I want the View to work like other views where you don't have to manage stuff like that from the Activity. *How do I determine if the parent Activity of a View has been destroyed?* (from the custom view itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a callback via which you will let your View know that the parent Activity has called onPause() and that the view should go into "pause" mode as well.

Unpause it when the activity gets the onResume() callback.

Comment: Cool... I think... can you add the callback via the View, so the program user of the custom view can still program using my custom view with out having to manage adding a callback?

Comment: You can have a public static void callThisOnPause() method in your View, sure.

Comment: additionally, the view should probably stop when its visibility is View.GONE so you might wanna overload the onVisibilityChanged() as well.

Comment: So if I am not mistaken, the programmer of the Activity class will still have to get a reference to my custom view and then call my onPause method from the Activities onPause method? I was trying to avoid that because you don't have to do that with Views like buttons, etc.

Comment: buttons don't have background threads in them. just document it nicely and it should do the trick... in the end, you're not making an API extension, just share-friendly code :)